# When is it good to compile Views and vice versa in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

When is it good to compile views in ASP.NET MVC and when would it be a bad choice to actually do it?

Answer (score 0):

Compiling the views is helpful in non debug compilation. It will only check compile time errors in your views.
There is no performance gain of doing this.
I suggest to enable it if you want to check these errors and let it disabled anyway.